# Calculating mean distances of points on map from other points

Tags: software-recommendations, mapping

I would like to draw a map of the US shaded by how far a person at each location would be from every other person in the US on average.

For my purposes, this could be, a map of US counties shaded by how far each county is from every other county (weighted by population density) on average.

Is there any software that could calculate such a "mean distance" value? (I have a basic level of familiarity with R).

Comment: Given a spatial database of counties you can compute the distance between all counties in R, yes. You can then compute a mean distance which you probably want to weight by population total rather than density. You could define the distance as the distance between centroids for each of the counties, which would be like assuming all people in a county live at that centroid point. Is that it?

Comment: No. That would only return one value. The point of what I'm trying to do is to find how distant or close counties are (conceptually similar to finding how rural or urban each county is, except that rural counties surrounded by rural counties would be considered more rural).

Comment: No, this would be computing the average weighted distance to all other populations from *each* county population. ie the average distance of a person at that location from another person in the rest of the population picked randomly from all other persons in the population. Which seems to be what you are asking for.

Comment: @Spacedman Thank you. It would have been clearer if you said "you can compute the distances between each of the counties" as the singular "distance" threw me off. I will have to look up how to calculate these en masse.